# Error during solution import in Visual Studio 2010 and when applying a web template

Tags: visual-studio, solution-package, site-template

I'm trying to import a solution from a wsp-file into a SharePoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010. The solution file results from a site template I exported using the "safe as template" option of a website.

After selecting the solution file I exported and specifying the single items I want to import (I select all), Visual Studio starts to import the solution. When it finished with the last item it shows an error message saying:

> The SharePoint solution import operation completed, but with errors. As a result, the project may not deploy successfully.

To check whether the import was OK or corrupted I packaged the solution again and try to redeploy it via code by creating a new website collection, uploading the solution file (packaged with Visual Studio) as an user solution (sandboxed solution) to the website collection, activating all features of the solution and applying the web template to the site collection's root website. At the point where the template is applied it takes a long time till a SPException occurs with the following message:

```
<nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

The inner exception's message is not really better, it says:

```
<nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack><nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

StackTrace:

```
  [COMException (0x8107058a): <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack><nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +172

[SPException: <nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27257906
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +27639363
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate) +1218
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) +1870
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

To validate that the error results from the solution import or packaging process I used the same code to create a website collection but this time using the original wsp-file which was not imported into Visual Studio and packaged again. And this time the web template can be applied without any error.

So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong when I imported the solution into Visual Studio or when I packaged the solution again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create the top-level SPWeb in a SPSite (Site Collection)? If so, we've had similar problems. We're able to package out a WSP from a sub-web (subsite of a site collection) and have it be used to create a new sub-web in a different SPSite or SPFarm.

We're also importing the package as "Farm Solution" in VS.

For the very first import error, trying creating your VS solution/project in C:\dev or another location closer to the root of your disk - it may be that some path names (of the imported features or modules) get too long.